# Tensorflow giving false results

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

This is the simplest problem I can come up with to test the accuracy of `tf`. But, it is not giving me satisfactory results. I have my own models and for a problem like this they even don't require training because error is already in zeros. Is there something wrong with my understanding/code etc? It should give exact answers i.e. `.11, .06` (my .net models do)

```
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [2]}));
model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});
const xs = tf.tensor2d([.01, .02, .03, .04, .05, .06], [3, 2]);
const ys = tf.tensor2d([.03, .07, .11], [3, 1]);
model.fit(xs, ys).then(() => {
model.predict(tf.tensor2d([.05,.06,.02,.03], [2, 2])).print();
});
```

Comment: You might want to tag the language you are writing in. Tensorflow main API is in python and this is not python.  Yet your only tag is tensorflow. But no matter. When you call fit() you are, in fact, training the model with SGD. And I am not sure why you think your model does not require training. You don't initialize weights or anything, so somehow your model needs to learn them.

Comment: Thanks @MadWombat, JS tag now added. I know TF requires training. Other custom made models can be different. For a problem such as this, even if you set all weights to, say "1", the predicted line should almost overlap the actual line because problem is too simple. That was what I meant. However TF (after training) still gives very unsatisfactory results. Why?

Comment: You do not initialize the weights, so they are probably set to 0. You do not pass any configs to fit(), so it probably does exactly one pass of backprop. So you end up with some pretty random results. I am not sure why you are surprised.

Comment: If you explicitly set your weights to 1, you will magically get much better results.

Comment: @MadWombat How do you initialize weights in tf.js?

Comment: You read the docs. In the docs for the dense layer you have an argument called config and in the config you can set a parameter kernelInitializer to 'ones'.
https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.13.0/#layers.dense

Comment: @MadWombat I worked it out. There was no problem except i used very few epochs every time believing 1 epoch means one pass through all weights.

Answer (score 0):

With your model, there is only one epoch for training. As a result the model is not giving false results as you suggested. I would rather say that it is giving random results. 
What happens is the following: during the first epoch the weights of your layer are initialized randomly. Simply changing the number of epochs will lead to better results.

It is also possible to customize the weights during initialization by calling an [initializer](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.13.0/#class:initializers.Initializer) for the value of the `kernelInitializer` when setting a [dense layer](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.13.0/#layers.dense).

Here is a model trained with 10 epochs that will perform better than the model with only one epoch

```js
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [2]}));
model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});
const xs = tf.tensor2d([.01, .02, .03, .04, .05, .06], [3, 2]);
const ys = tf.tensor2d([.03, .07, .11], [3, 1]);
model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 100}).then(() => {
model.predict(tf.tensor2d([.05,.06,.02,.03], [2, 2])).print();
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.13.0"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

A similar answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043855/simple-linear-regression-with-tensorflowjs/52612199#52612199)